# Turn on Windows Firewall false notification on boot

Tags: windows-11, firewall, notification-area

For months now, everytime i boot my laptop, i get a false notification to turn on Windows Firewall that is already on

[image]

This is so annoying and windows doesn't give an option for this specific notification to turn it off.

Any idea how to get rid of this once and for all?

Windows 11 23H2

Comment: Hard to know whether this is real or not. No such warning on any of my Windows 11 Pro machines. Go into Windows Defender and see if you can dismiss the warning there.

Comment: Already went there. Disabled all options in "Firewall Notification Settings". Message still appears on boot.

Comment: Something wrong with your Windows OS

Comment: Or there is malware, leading you to believe Firewall is functioning when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have some OS damage, try repairing with Windows 11 Repair Install.  If you believe you have malware, go to the third option under Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.

First option is Keep Everything:  If that works, great.

Second option to to Keep just Data.  This also keeps your Windows User Profile.  If this works, also great.  However if your User Profile has some damage, this will not fix it.

Third option is Keep Nothing.  This requires you to back everything up as Windows will delete everything and do a fresh install.   This will also delete any malware on your machine.

Good luck in correcting your machine.